# Ternário reduzido em PHP - Erro ou mal interpretado?

Tags: php

Olhando o manual temos esta descrição:

> 'The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE.
>   Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.'

#### Teste

```
$vlTeste1 = 5.25;
var_dump($vlTeste1 > 0 ?: 9.99); // true , em vez de 5.25
```

#### Situação

Segundo a descrição, esta incorreto fazer `$vl = (!empty($vl)) ?: null;` ?

Comment: mas ta certo ele vai retornar a expr1 que é ($vlTeste1 > 0) que é um bool true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Retornaria `5.25` se você fizesse assim:

```
var_dump($vlTeste1 ?: 9.99); //Retorna float(5.25)
```

Se você fizer

```
var_dump($vlTeste1 > 0 ?: 9.99); //Retorna bool(true) ou float(9.99)
```

Ele vai retornar o `$vlTeste1 > 0` e não o `$vlTeste1`, portanto `$vlTeste1 > 0` é uma condição o resultado é `boolean` e por este motivo no teu caso retornou `TRUE`.

Em outras palavras você está retornando o resultado condição e não a variável.

**Nota:** `0` e `NULL` se não usados com comparações "Identical" (por exemplo `===`) irão ser equivalentes ao `false`, por exemplo:

```
var_dump(NULL ?: 'foo'); //Retorna string(3) "foo"
var_dump(0 ?: 'foo'); //Retorna string(3) "foo"
```

Comment: No segundo exemplo retorna bool(true) ou float(9.99)

Comment: @AdirKuhn verdade