# O que signfica o operador "?:" no PHP?

Tags: php, operadores

O que significa o operador `?:` no PHP?

Exemplo:

```
$a = 0;

$b = false;

$c = 3;

echo $a ?: $b ?: $c;
```

Resultado:

> 3

O que exatamente ele está fazendo na expressão acima?

Isso é um ternário? Se não, como chama essa operação?

Comment: Relacionadas http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56830/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56812/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44133/101

Comment: Duplicada ou relacionada? As operações são diferentes nesse caso, não?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isto é o operador *ternário reduzido*, como dito nestas respostas:

- [Uso de ? e : em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56831/3635)
- [Ternário reduzido em PHP - Erro ou mal interpretado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59842/3635)

Se a condição passar:

```
$variavel = 10;
$variavel ?: 5; //Irá imprimir 10
```

Se for `0`, `false`, `NULL` ou uma string vazia:

```
$variavel = NULL;
$variavel ?: 5; //Irá imprimir 5
```

Ou seja a condição passar então usa o valor da condição, seria a mesma coisa que fazer isto:

```
$variavel ? $variavel : 5; //Irá imprimir 5
```

<sub>Fonte: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary</sub>

No seu exemplo `$a` é `0` e `$b` é `false`, como eu disse anteriormente, são valores que não passam na condição, como foi explicado pelo [@Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80906/3635) e por isto acaba indo para o `$c` que é o ultimo valor.

### Recomendação

É altamente recomendado evitar o "stacking" de expressões ternárias. O comportamento do PHP quando usando mais de um operador ternário no único comando não é óbvio para o interpretador, como você fez no seu exemplo:

```
 echo $a ?: $b ?: $c;
```

Então evite isto.

Comment: GuilhermeNascimento Boa resposta

Comment: Cara, interessante essa o interpretador, não sabia. para mim isso era igual aquela expressão em javascript `var x = x || 0`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters existe `a ? a : b` em javascript também, mas não existe `a ?: b`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o que eu quis dizer que o efeito é o mesmo

Comment: @WallaceMaxters a sim entendi, é o efeito é o mesmo, note que no php isto `$x || 0;` também é possível. Realmente não vejo diferença entre os dois no resultado final. (serviria como uma boa pergunta pra você formular, algo como, *qual a vantagem do ternario reduzido* ou *qual a diferença entre `?:` e `||`*) - Até mais

Answer (score 3):

Isso é um operador ternário com a **clausula** destinada ao resultado **true** vazio.

Logo: como `$a` é **falso** entra no segundo ternario que verifica se `$b` é verdadeiro ou falso e é **falso** entra no clausula **false** do segundo ternário que tem valor de `$c`.